# Split a column based on the delimiter in hive editor

Tags: hive

How to write a query to split a string like `'india|koria'` based on `'|'` into `india` and `korea`

I have tried this

```
select
    SUBSTRING('India|Korea', 1, position('|' in 'India|Korea') - 1) as first,
    SUBSTRING('India|Korea', position(',' in 'India|Korea') + 1)as second
```

but I get an error:

> error while compiling statement: failed: parseexceptio : cannot recognize input near 'in' '' India|Korea'' ')' in expression specification

Any help from anyone? Thanks in advance.

Note : I am running this query in hive editor.

Comment: I think `position' is not available in hive editor. any replacement for this to find a position for a particular character in a string ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the more recent versions of Hive support `substring_index()`.  For your logic, though, don't use `position()`, use `instr()`:

```
select substring('India|Korea', 1, instr('India|Korea', '|') - 1) as first,
       substring('India|Korea', instr('India|Korea', '|') + 1) as second
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it's worked.  I was looking for that 'instr' function.

Answer (score 0):

Try split UDF in hive:

```
select split('India|Korea', '\\|')[0], split('India|Korea', '\\|')[1];
+--------+--------+--+
|  _c0   |  _c1   |
+--------+--------+--+
| India  | Korea  |
+--------+--------+--+
1 row selected (0.136 seconds)
```

Also see: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF